# Data is not show in Table when leaded from Api due to Delay But When click any button It shown In Angular

Tags: angular, database, api, datatable

my data loaded from api after some delay but component loaded before that in log data is available but when I click on any Button on UI or change perPage limit data show in table.

ts function code this function is going called in ngOnInit()

```
getProducts(perPage:number,page:number){
   this.products=[];

   const  subscriber = this.productService.get_product(perPage,page)
     .pipe(first())
     .subscribe((products: productRootModel | undefined)=>{
       if (products) {
         for (let i = 0; i < products?.data.length; i++) {
           this.products.push(products?.data[i]);
         }
         this.spinner.hide();
         console.log( this.products);
       
       } else {
         console.log("error")

       }

     });
   this.unsubscribe.push(subscriber);
 }
```

service code

```
get_product(token: string,perPage:any,page:any): Observable<productRootModel> {

    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    });
    return this.http.get<productRootModel>(`${API_USERS_URL}/products/get/${perPage}?page=${page}`, {
      headers: httpHeaders,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({})
export class TableComponent {
  products = new Subject<any>();
  detalles$ = this.products.asObservable();
  getProducts(perPage:number,page:number){
   const  subscriber = this.productService.get_product(perPage,page)
     .pipe(first())
     .subscribe((products: productRootModel | undefined)=>{
       if (products) {
        this.products.next(products.data)
         this.spinner.hide();
       } else {
         console.log("error")

       }

     });
   this.unsubscribe.push(subscriber);
 }
}
```

html part

```
 <div *ngIf="detalles$ | async as data">
       <!-- The data is ready now! -->
       <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
         <!-- Your cells -->
       </tr>
       
    </div>
```